# How can I convert TimeSpan into int and show hours in quarterly fractions?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, timespan

I have an ASP.NET MVC application I am working on and need to calculate time. I have used `TimeSpan` to make the calculations in total time spent but I need to convert to int and instead of 7:30:00 for 7 and a half hours, I need 7.5. Below is the code I am working with. Please point me in the right direction.

```
public TimeSpan? MonDailyHours
{
        get
        {
            if (MonTimeIn.HasValue && MonTimeOut.HasValue)
            {
                TimeSpan allDay = MonTimeOut.Value.Subtract(MonTimeIn.Value);
                TimeSpan lunch = MonLunchEnd.Value.Subtract(MonLunchStart.Value);

                var Total = (int) allDay - lunch;
            }
            return null;
        }            
}
```

The attempt with `var Total` fails because it cannot convert. I know I am overlooking something simple but I am stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly 7.5 is not an int. Second, you've used both the Subtract method and the subtract operator, which are equivalent.

```cs
    var total = (MonTimeOut.Value - MonTimeIn.Value) - (MonLunchEnd.Value - MonLunchStart.Value);
    double hours = total.TotalHours;
```

Comment: Thanks for that I had actually just worked something out myself but this is much cleaner and uses the more appropriate `double` instead of `decimal` that I was about to use. Rock star!